# Validity / reliability of instrument used by 2 people at 2 sites

Tags: reliability, validity

How can the validity/reliability of a semi-structured interview tool be determined, conducted by two persons at two different sites separately? For instance, one person is using the tool with male respondents and another with female respondents differently at different places.

Answer (score 0):

The term "validity" encompasses a lot of different things, and "reliability" encompasses a few different things.

If you're interested in inter-rater reliability, there's no way to estimate that with this data, because no subjects are being assessed by both raters.

Other kinds of reliability and validity can be approached in the usual way, either by conducting separate analyses for the two raters or by using a single regression model with a dummy variable for rater.